# Pesquisar no banco de dados e retornar o valor - Laravel

Tags: php, banco-de-dados, laravel

Estou fazendo uma pesquisa no meu banco de dados, quero pegar o valor encontrado e salvar ele (São duas tabelas diferentes) mas o valor não está sendo salvo, está sendo salvo o numero 0.

Utilizo esse comando na minha controller:

```
$clientes = DB::table('cliente')->pluck('razaosocial', 'id');
return view('admin.contrato.create', ['cliente' => $clientes]);
```

E na minha view eu utilizo esse:

```
<div class="form-group col-md-5">
     {{ Form::label('cliente', 'Cliente') }}
         <select class="js-example-basic-multiple" name="cliente_id" >
            <option selected>Selecione o cliente</option>
              @foreach ($cliente as $cli)
                <option value="{{ $cli }}">{{ $cli }}</option>
              @endforeach
         </select>
</div>
```

Quando utilizo isso me aparece os dados, mas não consigo salva-los. Não manjo muito de PHP, alguém sabe como posso solucionar?

Comment: Lei um pouco sobre Eloquent nesse link: https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent  e veja como os objetos são persistidos no banco

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tente:

```
@foreach ($cliente as $cli)
    <option value="{{ $cli->id }}">{{ $cli->razaosocial }}</option>
@endforeach
```

Comment: Deu certo, muito obrigado !

Comment: Legal. Agora vi que coloquei um sinal de igual antes de '->'.
Mas deves ter ajustado. Vou editar.
Uma dica, use o Eloquent.

Answer (score 0):

Você está passando a razaosocial para o banco de dados, 
Tente dessa maneira:

```
<div class="form-group col-md-5">
     {{ Form::label('cliente', 'Cliente') }}
         <select class="js-example-basic-multiple" name="cliente_id" >
            <option selected>Selecione o cliente</option>
              @foreach ($cliente as $key => $value)
                <option value="{{ $value }}">{{ $key }}</option>
              @endforeach
         </select>
</div>
```

Comment: Não deu o valor passado ainda foi 0.